# Fix.4.2 protocol implementation(Fiximulator - Banzai(client)) message log

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

I am trying to implement Fix.4.2 protocol, but It is difficult to understand the message log I attached below. Here Logon(35=A) request was sent with MsgSeqNum(34=1) from client. Then for testing ResendRequest and SequenceReset session level messages I sent a NewOrderSingle request with MsgSeqNum=7 (instead of MsgSeqNum=2, as subsequent messages should have incremeted msgseqnum after logon request). As expected MsgSeqNum is too high than recieved one Fiximulator responded with a ResendRequest(35=2) to send from 2 to 0 (i.e., from 2 to 7). Here why the Fiximulator is not waiting for client's reply ? instead it is sending an heartbeat message. Why the client is sending ResendRequest in response to ResendRequest of Fiximulator instead of sending SequenceReset message ?.

Also explain remaining cases if possible.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your status of ResetOnLogon in your config file for the acceptor ? Default value is N so it isn't being reset. Always check your config file or try debugging to figure out issues.

> ResetOnLogon  Determines if sequence numbers should be reset when recieving a logon request. Acceptors only